# Создание и правильная инициализация массива списков

Tags: c, алгоритм, список, динамические-массивы

Для реализации одного алгоритма мне нужен массив списков. Вот как я его создаю:

```
list *buckets = (list*)malloc(n*sizeof(list));
```

Я подозреваю, что будут проблемы в его использовании из-за того, что сейчас этот массив содержит мусор. Как правильно инициализировать этот массив, чтобы потом можно было обращаться к списку по его адресу в массиве и добавлять в выбранный список элементы функцией insert? Вот так:

```
insert(buckets[0], data);
```

Попытался сделать так:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    *(buckets + i) = NULL;
```

Но вижуал студия помечает вторую строчку как ошибку. Кстати, она считает ошибкой даже те конструкции, которые корректны в чистом си (насчет корректности моего цикла я не уверен).

Comment: А что за списки у вас? И что насчет массива указателей на списки - допустимо ли такое?

Comment: Односвязные списки. Если блочная сортировка реализуется при помощи массива связных списков, которые сортируются вставками, то да, допустимо. К тому же вот здесь есть попытки написать такой массив, но я не понял принцип его инициализации. https://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/2787408.all

Comment: То есть у вас не std::list?

Comment: Нет, я пишу на си, но компилирую в вижуал студии. Надо будет почитать, как можно сделать компиляцию из FAR, и студия будет не нужна, и ее упоминание не будет вводить в заблуждение, что я пишу на C++.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что на самом деле вам нужно создать массив указателей на начальные элементы списков, то есть на их `header(s)`.

Это будет выглядеть следующим образом, если вы хотите динамически выделять память вод данный массив

```
list **buckets = ( list ** )malloc( n * sizeof( list * ) );
```

Для инициализации элементов массива нулем вы можете использовать стандартную функцию `memset`, объявленную в заголовке `<string.h>`. Например

```
#include <string.h>

//...

memset( buckets, 0, n * sizeof( list *) );
```

То же самое вы можете сделать, используя обычный цикл

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i) buckets[i] = NULL;
```

Если ваш компилятор поддерживает **Variable Length Arrays (VLA)**, то вы могли бы записать

```
List * buckets[n] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Я бы хотел написать максимально переносимый код, который не зависит от того, каким компилятором его компилировать. Хотя иногда встречаются классные вещи, которые не входят в стандарт - например, указатели на метки, между которыми помещается вирусный код, который затем шифруется от указателя на начало до указателя на конец.

Comment: И да, массив должен содержать root'ы списков. Вот как-то так создается список: https://ideone.com/w75OWW

Answer (score 2):

Небольшое дополнение: Для выделения памяти инициализированной нулями под массив, можно использовать функцию [calloc](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=calloc)

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение. Совсем из головы вылетело.:)